Cannot access files in Firebase Storage after regenerating service account key due to SignatureDoesNotMatch error
I recently discovered that my Firebase service account key was exposed, leading Firebase to disable it for security reasons. After generating a new service account key, I found that I couldn’t access certain files that had been signed using the previous key. These files were accessible through URLs saved in my database, but now every time I try to access one, I receive this error:
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Details>
<StringToSign>GET 32503680000 /meditourglobal-ea15d.appspot.com/profile_pictures/IMG_0007.PNG</StringToSign>
</Error>

It appears that these URLs are no longer valid because the new service account key doesn’t match the previous one used for signing. I need a way to regain access to these files or to re-sign the URLs so they function correctly with the new key.
I tried accessing the URLs as usual, expecting them to work with the new service account key. I was hoping the key reset wouldn’t affect previously generated links, but it appears that Firebase Storage URL signatures are bound to the specific service account key. I’d appreciate guidance on how to update these URLs, regenerate valid links, or any other workaround to restore access to these files without breaking access permissions for existing links
Here is an example url to check
https://storage.googleapis.com/meditourglobal-ea15d.appspot.com/profile_pictures/IMG_0007.PNG?GoogleAccessId=firebase-adminsdk-faw9m%40meditourglobal-ea15d.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=32503680000&Signature=UN828W2lxNdUDHhsFZzMfw0J6Sh0pG2i8wsMaUgA2FUqqlGRUMK2yoV7m0De2leQbQXUOhgOP%2BQq4XBC4WXU8NzE139dCX5z%2Fb%2BZ%2BzmL5sPp2OtD%2FCCef4%2BFpYuRzL%2BUfzWkYA9Q6g%2BAttNMDMHPWu2zUt8OlaEyc6C52U72HRlGQCw6ASur%2BiQFoxwSxQrR3Osj3qTy6ashvstClZYNzxdVZlvIJdfl2325m65wIFyIhgTv9zWevXpomGkBb4zmlS3RhW4nJ2rEFm1hra6n%2BDSJQPyQTb0K93obtQgqE80H7MvRy3kz8VMMvoZmdSX4OqXRotGyoQ7c6S7l3WwDFA%3D%3D
Here's how i have configured the service in my code
I have setup connection to firebase using admin sdk as described in the snippet below


require('dotenv').config(); // Load environment variables from .env

const serviceAccount = {
  type: process.env.type,
  project_id: process.env.project_id,
  private_key_id: process.env.private_key_id,
  private_key: process.env.private_key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  client_email: process.env.client_email,
  client_id: process.env.client_id,
  auth_uri: process.env.auth_uri,
  token_uri: process.env.token_uri,
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: process.env.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
  client_x509_cert_url: process.env.client_x509_cert_url,
  universe_domain: process.env.universe_domain
};

// Example: using this with Firebase Admin SDK
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: "meditourglobal-ea15d.appspot.com",
});



and the endpoint to upload files to firebase storage is as follows


async uploadFile(req, res) {
    try {
      if (req.file) {
        const file = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
        const imageRef = bucket.file(
          `profile_pictures/${req.file.originalname}`
        );

        bucket
          .upload(req.file.path, {
            destination: imageRef,
            metadata: {
              contentType: req.file.mimetype,
            },
          })
          .then(() => {
            // Delete the local file after uploading
            fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);

            // Get the public URL of the uploaded image
            imageRef
              .getSignedUrl({
                action: "read",
                expires: "01-01-3000", // Set an expiration date if needed
              })
              .then((signedUrls) => {
                const imageUrl = signedUrls[0];
                return res.status(200).json({
                  fileUrl: imageUrl,
                });
                // })
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                return res.status(500).send("Error getting signed URL.");
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            return res.status(500).send("Error uploading image.");
          });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
          status: false,
          message: "Please select an image",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
        status: "Failure",
        error: error.message,
      });
    }
  },




It’s a good idea to include code, errors and structures as text, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at No Images Please

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
